# jQuery and Array type classes

Tags: jquery, html, document-ready

I'm trying to access all inputs with the following class:

```
validate['number']
```

Of course sometimes some of them are:

```
validate['required', 'number']
```

So I need all that have `number` there. This is part of a Chronoform system that makes these classes.

I have tried this, figured if it worked I would go from there and make it work for all that even had `required` or `alpha`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".validate['number']").change(function() {
    if(this.value <= '') {
      this.value = '0';
    }
  });
});
```

But no go, it won't find them. So how do I find classes like this and their sub parts? I don't even know what to call these kinds of classes since I've never seen them before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names with special characters can't be accessed directly with `.classname`.

Instead, you need to use this selector: `[class~="validate['number']"]`

Comment: Awesome! It worked this way for me  `jQuery('input[class~="validate[\'number\']"]')`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you escape special characters properly. Try this:

```
$(".validate\\[\\'required\\'\\]")
```

From the jQuery API docs:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

More on selector escaping: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

I would even suggest that you extend jQuery's support for pseudo selectors like this:

```
(function () {
    var rRequired = /\bvalidate\[[^\]]*\brequired\b[^\]]*\]/,
        rAlpha = /\bvalidate\[[^\]]*\balpha\b[^\]]*\]/,
        rNumber = /\bvalidate\[[^\]]*\bnumber\b[^\]]*\]/;

    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        mandatory: function(elem) {
            return rRequired.test(elem.className)
        },

        number: function (elem) {
            return rNumber.test(elem.className)
        },

        alpha: function (elem) {
            return rAlpha.test(elem.className)
        }
    });
})();
```

Then you can use much simpler selectors in your code:

```
$('input:mandatory')
$('input:number')
$('input:alpha')
```

*Note: I tried to make ":required" pseudo-selector but it doesn't work for some reason, hence `:mandatory` instead.*